# Change phone state to vibrate

Tags: android, gps

I am creating an app when my phone enters a predefined location it must automatically turn to vibration mode via gps i.e. when my latitude and longitude match within a radius of 1 km, then phone should change its state to vibration mode.Your valuable answer will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to make a service for checking your predefined location.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add Permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
v.vibrate(500);

For Distance :

Location locationA = new Location("point A");

locationA.setLatitude(latA);
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");

locationB.setLatitude(latB);
locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

Comment: The latitude and longitude at every point differs.So i actually wanted the phone should vibrate respective to the locations(within 1km) whatever the long-lat is,provided it should be present within that 1km.

Comment: ok u need to keep track of the same the point u wanna vibrate the above code works fine..in case any query u can add comments

Comment: Mam,even if i change my location to 5cm then also the long and lat differs.How to track these positions is the big trouble

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    AudioManager audio_mngr = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 

audio_mngr.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

Comment: I wanted the phone should vibrate respective to the locations(within 1km) whatever the long-lat is,provided it should be present within that 1km.

Comment: If phone within the range enable vibrate mode if not enable Ring mode.

Comment: This was my question.I am asking for the code or related help.thnx

Answer (score 0):

Set the vibration  permission in your manifest file like this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

And use below code for vibration when you enters into your predefined location.

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);     
// Vibrate for 300 milliseconds
v.vibrate(300);
```

Comment: Mam,I actually wanted the phone to vibrate respective to the locations.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will do 2 things :

- listen to location updates
- change the ringer mode

**1/ Listen to location updates**

See here how to implement that in your app : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates

Call the proper LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates() method according to your preferences:

- which provider to use (GPS is more accurate but consumes more battery)
- how often (ms or meters) do you want the update to be sent
- send an intent or call a listener as in the example above
- etc

**2/ Change the ringer mode**

Whenever your app receives a location update, you get a Location object with coordinates. Assuming that you have predefined locations in your app to compare with, you can use Location.distanceBetween() to know how far you are from a predefined location.
If you are close enough, then change the ringer mode. The code given by Homo Sapiens seems ok.

**3/ Don't forget to set back the ringer to the normal mode when you're not close to any predefined location !**

HTH

PS: I haven't tried any of this, it's just some quick research on the Android doc...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
v.vibrate(500);
```

Note:

Don't forget to include permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```